# Como puedo convertir un numero entero a decimal en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy consumiendo una api que hice. pero hay un atributo que recibe el cual tiene que ser tipo float. tengo un formulario con un input tipo number en el cual tomo su valor y lo convierto a decimal con parceFloat(). pero si un usuario introduce  "5.00" : parceFloat retorna 5 el cual no es decimal.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo que no es flotante (no se llama decimal)? 5 es un flotante con su parte decimal igual a cero. Si deseas que se muestre su parte decimal hasta cierta cantidad de dígitos, entonces eso ya es tema de formato de salida. Si un usuario introduce `5.00` en tu `input` y tú le aplicas `parseFloat`, el valor será numérico flotante. Si haces un `console.log` de ese valor y te muestra 5 es porque la parte decimal, al ser cero, se omite por defecto. Si haces `console.log(isFloat(valor))` te mostrará `true`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras muchas gracias, ahora entiendo mejor, pero como podria mostrar el 5 con formato de salida 5.00? ya que la api no lo reconoce como flotante? o puedo hacer algo en la api?

Comment: Si lo necesitas como valor numérico, para qué quieres los decimales. Si tu API espera un valor flotante, debería trabajar correctamente con el valor que le vas a enviar, siempre que sea numérico. Falta más información en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Utiliza el metodo `toFixed` con el parametro 2, esto no te dara un decimal, si no un string con parte decimal, en tu caso te pone 5 sin mas porque para JS, 5.00 y 5 son lo mismo, y en terminos de nivel mas bajo es mas factible siempre para las maquinas usar numeros enteros, si lo que quieres es luego usar ese `5.00` pero para mostrar informacion entonces te vale el `toFixed` sin embargo si vas a seguir haciendo calculos con ese `5.00`, entonces simplemente utiliza lo que te esta dando el `parseFloat`.